# tsql procedure return values asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

What I am trying to do: I have created a T-SQL stored procedure that returns a single column from multiple tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_] 
    (@am VARCHAR(12)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(128)

    DECLARE Tbl CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
         SELECT LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 27) AS Tbl 
         FROM ap.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
         WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE LEFT('STORED_PRODUCTS_FR_[0-9]_%', 27)
           AND SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 20, 2) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
           AND SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 23, 1) = '_'
         ORDER BY
             CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 24, 4)) ASC,
             CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 21, 2)) ASC

    OPEN Tbl

    FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl INTO @DBName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)
        SET @sql = 'SELECT [column 3] FROM ' + @DBName + ' WHERE [COLUMN 4] = ' + @am + '';

        EXEC(@sql)

        FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl INTO @DBName
    END
END

CLOSE Tbl
DEALLOCATE Tbl
```

Then in asp.net, I want to populate a gridview...

```
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter();

    string message = string.Empty;
    con.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "Search_";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@am", am.Text);   
    cmd.Connection = con;

    dt.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dt.Fill(dTable);

    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

That only returns a single row (the first one) of the stored procedure.

What am I doing wrong? It seems that the values are overwriting themselves.

Any help from anyone....

Comment: Is your SP works in SQL Server as you want?

Comment: Yes.It returns 2 rows as expected.

Comment: Run your stored procedure in SQL management studio, see how the data is returned there. You likely have two tables with one row not one table with two rows

Comment: This code will return a DataTable for each result, and end up binding only the first table with it's only result into your DataGrid

Comment: I get not 2 rows as i post but 3.I did not notice the last.
The 2 first rows have values.
The last one is named as "Return Value" with value 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure returns both rows, but since each row is being selected in a different select statement, the `DataAdapter` can only use the first one returning to fill the `DataTable`. If you where filling a `DataSet`, it would contain 2 `DataTable` instances.

Please note your stored procedure suggest you have a flaw in your database design - having multiple tables that stores the same type of entities is a bad design for a database. However, I'm not sure that's the case here.

Anyway, to solve this problem with a quick patch, you can change your procedure to something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_] (@am varchar(12)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DBName varchar(128)
    declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''

    DECLARE Tbl CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
    select LEFT(TABLE_NAME,27) as Tbl from ap.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    where TABLE_NAME like left('STORED_PRODUCTS_FR_[0-9]_%',27)
    and SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME , 20,2) like '%[0-9]%'
    and SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME , 23,1) = '_'
    order by CONVERT(int , substring(TABLE_NAME,24,4)) asc ,
    CONVERT(int , substring(TABLE_NAME,21,2)) asc   

    OPEN Tbl

    FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl INTO @DBName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @sql += 'union all select [column 3] from '+@DBName+' WHERE [COLUMN 4] ='+@am+' ';
        FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl INTO @DBName
    END

    CLOSE Tbl
    DEALLOCATE Tbl

    SET @sql = STUFF(@Sql, 1, 10, '') -- Remove the first union all
    exec(@sql)
END
```

Comment: I just test it and it works..The above solution work like charm..Thank you

Comment: Glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your script, the last `end` should be placed after `DEALLOCATE Tbl` and for calling the sp which returns multiple recordset better to use DataSet or DataReader:

```
var dataset = new DataSet();
using(var cnnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.Search_", cnnn);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
}
dataset.Tables => gives u all the results of exec(@sql)
```

since each result set retuns the same column name and structure you can merge them all in one tb:

```
var allTbs = dataset.Tables[0].Copy();
for(int i = 1; i < dataset.Tables.Count; i++)
    allTbs.Merge(dataset.Tables[i]);
```